# SQLite report on conflict

Tags: sqlite, triggers, database-trigger

I'm using `INSERT OR IGNORE` and `INSERT OR REPLACE` , I'm trying to get SQLite to report whenever the `OR IGNORE` or `OR REPLACE` condition occurred.

I looked into using `TRIGGER` but wasn't able to get it to work as expected.
The desired behaviour is to raise a warning when the `OR` condition was true.

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible to combine AFTER INSERT/DELETE triggers with [user-defined functions](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html) to report whether some rows got inserted/deleted or not.

However, these statements are intended to be used when you do not care about which case actually happened.
The easiest way to detect if the same value already exists in the table is to run a SELECT.

Comment: But than I would need to run SELECT on each insertion , right? Hence the trigger seem to cover my use case pretty well. I'll check into the link you supplied.